# Dissolve connected lines until line forks

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I have a lot of small lines which i need to connect, but only if connection point has 2 connected lines. When there is a fork with 3 or more connected lines, i need them to stay separated. Is there a way to do this using existing tools or do I need a custom script?

Answer (score 2):

***Dissolve*** all into one and then ***v.clean(break)***. I tried something like this before asking question, but i guess i did something wrong the first time.